# "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" from cron

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

Suddenly I'm starting to get these log warnings every minute:

```
2016-01-14T15:03:39+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in C:\Bitnami\magento-1.9.2.2-1-3\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Cron\Model\Observer.php on line 67
```

I looked at the code and it comes from here:

```
/** @var $schedule Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule */
        foreach ($schedules->getIterator() as $schedule) {
            $jobConfig = $jobsRoot->{$schedule->getJobCode()};
            if (!$jobConfig || !$jobConfig->run) {
                $jobConfig = $defaultJobsRoot->{$schedule->getJobCode()}; // <-- here!!!!!
                if (!$jobConfig || !$jobConfig->run) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            $this->_processJob($schedule, $jobConfig);
        }
```

I have an extension with some cronjobs but I removed it completely and it still happens.

I don't know why it started all of the sudden, or why this happens. I can't seem to be able to get rid of it and stacktrace don't do any good either because its something internal of Magento.

Edit: reset entire server and still no good. :/

How do I deal with this??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The missing object is `$defaultJobsRoot` which is initialized a few lines above:

```
$defaultJobsRoot = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/crontab/jobs');
```

This means, Magento can find *no* cronjobs in the configuration. Since the core modules already define quite a few cronjobs, there is something wrong with your core files or, more likely, the configuration cache.

If cleaning the cache does not help, a full hard disk (no space left or no free inodes left) might cause an incomplete cache like this.

Comment: it wasn't a full disk and cleaning the cache didn't work. eventually I reinstalled (!) magento and the problem was solved.. I hope it won't come back as I won't always be able to do this extreme solution. thanks!

Comment: @Ness this sounds like you had changes in the core. Good thing it works again.

Answer (score 1):

Somtimes chaging the site domain from https to http may cause this issue.
A recreation of the magento cron jobs file on the server might help (delete of crontab and recreate it), to get the new configuration correctly.